# how to create table form the result set of another query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table from the result set of the SQL query but I got syntax error at select and I struck at that point

these are ways which I tried

```
create table schedulewidgetfix
 as
 (select * from PRSNLOCPROFMM

where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID in

(select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID from PERSONALLOCATNPROF where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID

not in (select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID from PRSNLOCPROFORGMM)))
```

and the other way I tried is

```
SELECT *
INTO schedulewidgetfix
FROM

  (select * from PRSNLOCPROFMM

where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID in

(select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID from PERSONALLOCATNPROF where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID

not in (select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID from PRSNLOCPROFORGMM)))
```

here I got syntax error at the closing bracket 
so what is the way to create the table

Comment: Don't do this.  It's a bad practice.  Best practice is to explicitly list all the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You were close. You could either add an alias to the subquery like this.

```
SELECT * --you should list the columns here though instead of using *
INTO schedulewidgetfix
FROM

  (select * from PRSNLOCPROFMM

where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID in

(select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID from PERSONALLOCATNPROF where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID

not in (select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID from PRSNLOCPROFORGMM))) x
```

Or a cleaner approach would be to eliminate that subquery entirely like this.

```
SELECT * --you should list the columns here though instead of using *
INTO schedulewidgetfix
FROM PRSNLOCPROFMM
where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID in
(
    select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID 
    from PERSONALLOCATNPROF 
    where PERSONALLOCATNPROFID not in (select PERSONALLOCATNPROFID from PRSNLOCPROFORGMM)
)
```